# Why does my Firefox open two windows when launched by URLs in other applications?

Tags: macos, firefox

I'm using Firefox v3.6.6 as my default browser on OS X 10.6.4.  For a while now I've noticed that whenever I open a URL from another application (e.g., PDFs in Preview, Steam, OSX help pages, Terminal) *two* Firefox windows are opened, with the requested URL in the second.

If Firefox is already open this doesn't happen; the URL is opened in a new tab in an existing window, as per my Firefox preferences.  The symptom doesn't occur with Safari as the default browser.  Similarly, no matter what the default browser, `open -a Firefox http://superuser.com` gives the double window whereas `open -a Safari http://superuser.com` does not.

For the life of me I can't work out why this happens.  Is there an OSX `plist` or Firefox `about:config` setting that I should be checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not you; it's your [browser](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=531552).